# Qlistview Selectionchanged event not found in Qt?

Tags: qt, qlistview

Qlistview Selectionchanged event not found in Qt 
What is the equivalent of selection changed event in Qlistview in Qt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just about selection, so the focus?

When using QListView:

```
QAbstractItemView::currentChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous )
```

When using QListWidget, you can also use:

```
QListWidget::currentItemChanged ( QListWidgetItem * current, QListWidgetItem * previous )
```

Docs:

- [QListView::currentChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#currentChanged)
- [QListWidget::currentItemChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentItemChanged)

Comment: Don't know if this worked at some time but it doesn't seem to work in qt 4.8 since QListView currentChanged is protected for whatever reason.

Comment: I can confirm [`QAbstractItemView::currentChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qabstractitemview.html#currentChanged) is protected in [Qt 5.7](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qlistview.html) and this would only be useful if you were trying to make your own ListView implementation.

Comment: Can you just edit the QListView part out of your answer? The QListWidget part is correct but the QListView part is wrong and Mat is right on this.

Answer (score 17):

The `selectionChanged` signal is generated by the [`QItemSelectionModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html) attached to the view, not the view widget itself.

You can get that model by calling `selectionModel()` on the view object, or by adding your own with `setSelectionModel()`.

This applies both to `QListView` and `QListWidget`, since this behavior is handled by the `QAbstractItemView` which both inherit.

(Class hierarchy is `QAbstractItemView < QListView < QListWidget`.)

See [Handling selections in item view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-in-item-views) for more information.

Comment: Sorry. See my edited question i am referring to list widget not listview.

Comment: It will be a duplicate dude.Pls give your answer here only.Thanks.

Comment: @user662285 I really wish you would not have edited your question after the fact, you should have posted a different question for QListWidget because they are totally different Widgets.